# What is faster: sending file with post request or storing it in postgres database?

Tags: database, postgresql, http-post

We have a system, which has a very slow working speed.
We would like to make it faster and more efficient.
Right now, we send the files from one server to another with post request (the file size is approximately 150Mb).
Is it possible that storing the same file in a database (such as postgres) will improve the efficiency of this system?
The server is working with kubernetes + kafka.

Post request from one server to another, where files are sent through the form.

Due to internet shortage, this takes too much time (not efficient).

Comment: Storing and/or retrieving the file from the database will also go through the internet so you can't avoid that. Databases can't magically transfer data between computers.

Comment: Caching data can improve performance however sending a file over the network regardless of destination is going to be the same, and storing in a RDBMS is likely to be no faster, probably slower, than in the file system. Of course, like any performance improvement you do some R&D and test it.

Answer (score -1):

Storing files to database is not a good option instead of file system but if it is required for any reason then try to compress files when you are inserting them, and decompress while retrieving but note that this is for only very large files like in GBs. files under MBs don't need compression postgres sql have good compression by default for files stuff.

Comment: Do you mean compress/decompress instead of encrypt/decrypt?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about it, compress/decompress